# What does this function mean and how do I prove it's linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have never seen a function that looks like $f(x, y)$, and there is a sample question on an old exam where I have to prove that something like this is a linear transformation, and I don't know where to start. Here is the function:

$T(x, y)$ = $\left(\frac{x + y}{\sqrt 2}, \frac{x - y}{\sqrt 2}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your linear transformation is from the Euclidean 2 space ($R^2$) to $R^2$, by definition of linear transformation you need to check 2 conditions.

1. $T(a+b) = T(a) + T(b)$, where a and b are both elements of $R^2$
2. $T(ca) = cT(a)$, where $c$ is a constant (a real number) and $a$ in an element of $R^2$

Comment: I already know that; I was able to prove that 2. is true, but I am not sure how to prove 1. is true.

Comment: To prove 1 start like this, take $a = (x_1,y_1)$ and $b = (x_2,y_2)$. Then calculate  $T(a) + T(b)$ first and then calculate $T(a+b)$. Check if they are equal. And they are equal.

Comment: In fact a more easier way to show that the $T$ is a linear transformation is to show that you can write T as a matrix $1/sqrt(2)* [[1,1],[1,-1]]$ multiplied by your vector $(x,y)$.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help!